# What is the maximum diameter of Starsurge?

Tags: league-of-legends

While this may not be very practical, I still am interested in knowing. Aurelion Sol's Star

> Aurelion Sol fires the core of a newborn star in the target direction, which expands as long as it remains within the Outer Limit

I would like to know the maximum diameter you can make it expand to in Summoners Rift.

Comment: It's infinite, but I suspect you already knew that. What you're asking is in the lines of "how long can he charge it so it grows?", which would require a fair bit of experimentation with heavy MS buffs. **However** I've seen it being done from base to base and it becomes almost the full screen

Comment: @Oak if the map were unbounded, then yes it would be infinite, however the distance he can travel is finite, therefore the diameter is finitely bounded. Also if you have boots of swiftness + homeguard + ludens, you should have plenty of movespeed to keep up with it.

Comment: I'll look it up; I saw a video where they attempted of doing the maximum by going full Movespeed Ao Shin with other champions granting speedbuffs; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ym_LxIpBDDM is pretty big, but this isn't the video I waas looking for

Comment: In a custom game I ran a star from my base to the enemies and it was larger than the size of the lane.

Comment: All that was required is the wanderer mastery(3% out of combat MS), boots of swiftness with alacrity enchant, plus ludens echo for the 10% MS. Edit: after watching the linked video it looks like the star stopped growing after a certain point.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it in a custom game with a few friends and estimate it to have a radius of ~700 and a diameter of ~1400 making it one of the largest AoE spells in the game.